# Select a Dojo ComboBox item using Javascript

Tags: javascript, dojo

I'm automating a third party website that uses Dojo components, as far as of the ComboBoxes I can change the selection by setting the value property but that won't trigger the change event, what's the trick to simulate a manual selection on these Dojo ComboBoxes?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should trigger the change event though, that's the default behavior of setting the value of a widget. If you use the following code to add the event and change the value:

```js
comboBox.on("change", function(val) {
    console.log("New value: " + val); 
});
comboBox.set("value", "Alaska");
```

Then you will see that it prints the statement of the onChange event into the console, so you would see:

```
New value: Alaska
```

If you don't want to trigger the event, then you also have to add a third parameter to the `set()` function:

```js
comboBox.set("value", "Alaska", false);
```

I also made an example on JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/w2sfsv2f/

Comment: I just wanted to let you know that for the particular web page that I was working on I couldn't get the change event to fire using the sample you provided so what I did was to look at the page source code and look for the code that was assigned to that combo box control, that allowed me to trigger the same functions as if I had manually chosen an item from the combo. Thanks.